# How to add build step in team city to run Node Js unit tests (Mocha framework)

Tags: teamcity

I have a NodeJs application. Currently I am using team city for build and deployment of this application.
Now I want to run unit test cases before deployment. I have used Mocha framework with Chai to write test cases.
I don't see any runner type for Mocha or Node Js in team city.

I know some plugin is needed to be installed on teamcity server.

does any one know what is the plugin and what steps I need to follow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to install any specific TeamCity plugin, you have to use test reporter capable of writing TeamCity [service messages](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity), e.g. [mocha-teamcity-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-teamcity-reporter), which is just another npm package.

You'll get you tests consumed by TeamCity after you run `mocha --reporter mocha-teamcity-reporter test` in your build step, so `Command-Line Runner` may be used for this purpose.

It is a good practice to extract this command to a separate [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) in your `package.json`, e.g:

```
"test:ci": "mocha --reporter mocha-teamcity-reporter test"
```

and use `npm run test:ci` in your build step.

Comment: it worked. only point want to add here is that I had to use --exit because Mocha doesn't stop execution automatically after executing all test cases. I was reading on internet and found that it's issue with Mocha 4.